# DuplexChannelFactory < Reflection Interface >

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, duplex-channel

Using **TypeGenerator** Class

```
   public class TypeGenerator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// internal cache for already generated types
        /// </summary>
        private static Dictionary<Type, Type> asyncTypeCache = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();      

        /// <summary>
        /// provides a cache for the modules
        /// </summary>
        private static Dictionary<string, ModuleBuilder> moduleBuilderCache = new Dictionary<string, ModuleBuilder>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates the Async version of the TSync type.
        /// the generate type repects the AsyncPattern and it is already decorated with attributes for WCF operations
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TSync">The Sync version of type</typeparam>
        /// <returns>A type that is the Async version of the TSync type, that implements the AsyncPattern for WCF</returns>
        public Type GenerateAsyncInterfaceFor<TSync>() where TSync : class
        {
            Type syncType = typeof(TSync);

            if (asyncTypeCache.ContainsKey(syncType)) return asyncTypeCache[syncType];

            if (!syncType.IsInterface) throw new InvalidOperationException("Only interface type could be transformed");

            var asynchAssemblyName = string.Format("{0}.Async", syncType.Namespace);

            TypeBuilder typeBuilder =
                GetModuleBuilder(asynchAssemblyName)
                .DefineType(
                    string.Format("{0}.Async.{1}", syncType.Namespace, syncType.Name),
                    (syncType.IsPublic ? TypeAttributes.Public : 0) |
                    TypeAttributes.Abstract |
                    TypeAttributes.Interface);

            foreach (var method in syncType.GetAllInterfaceMethods())
            {
                AddBeginAsynchVersionForMethod(typeBuilder, method, @"http://tempuri.org");
                AddEndAsynchVersionForMethod(typeBuilder, method);
            }

            var serviceContractConstructor = typeof(ServiceContractAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
            var attribuiteBuilder =
                new CustomAttributeBuilder(
                    serviceContractConstructor,
                    new object[0]);

            typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attribuiteBuilder);

            Type asyncType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

            asyncTypeCache.Add(syncType, asyncType);
            return asyncType;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a End verison of a sync method, that implements the AsyncPattern
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="typeBuilder">the tipebuilder where the type is being building</param>
        /// <param name="method">information about the sync version of the method</param>
        private void AddEndAsynchVersionForMethod(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, MethodInfo method)
        {
            string endMethodName = string.Format("End{0}", method.Name);

            var parameters =
                method.GetParameters()
                .Select(x =>
                    new
                    {
                        Type = x.ParameterType,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        Attributes = x.Attributes,
                    })
                .ToList();

            parameters.Add(
                new
                {
                    Type = typeof(IAsyncResult),
                    Name = "asyncResult",
                    Attributes = ParameterAttributes.None,
                });

            var methodBuilder =
                typeBuilder
                .DefineMethod(
                    endMethodName,
                    method.Attributes,
                    method.CallingConvention,
                    method.ReturnType,
                    parameters.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray());

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
            {
                var parameter = parameters[i];
                methodBuilder.DefineParameter(i + 1, parameter.Attributes, parameter.Name);             
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Begin verison of a sync method, that implements the AsyncPattern
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="typeBuilder">the tipebuilder where the type is being building</param>
        /// <param name="method">information about the sync version of the method</param>
        private void AddBeginAsynchVersionForMethod(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, MethodInfo method, string nameSpace)
        {
            string beginMethodName = string.Format("Begin{0}", method.Name);

            var parametersTypeList = method.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToList();
            var parametersNameList = method.GetParameters().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            var parametersAttributeList = method.GetParameters().Select(x => x.Attributes).ToList();

            parametersTypeList.Add(typeof(AsyncCallback));
            parametersAttributeList.Add(ParameterAttributes.None);
            parametersNameList.Add("callBack");

            parametersTypeList.Add(typeof(object));
            parametersAttributeList.Add(ParameterAttributes.None);
            parametersNameList.Add("statusObject");

            var methodBuilder = 
                typeBuilder
                .DefineMethod(
                    beginMethodName,
                    method.Attributes,
                    method.CallingConvention,
                    typeof(IAsyncResult),
                    parametersTypeList.ToArray());

            for (int i = 0; i < parametersTypeList.Count(); i++)
            {
                methodBuilder.DefineParameter(i + 1, parametersAttributeList[i], parametersNameList[i]);
            }

            var operationContractConstructor = typeof(OperationContractAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
            var asynchPatternProperty = typeof(OperationContractAttribute).GetProperty("AsyncPattern");

            var actionProperty = typeof(OperationContractAttribute).GetProperty("Action");
            var actionValue = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", nameSpace, method.DeclaringType.Name, method.Name);

            var replyActionProperty = typeof(OperationContractAttribute).GetProperty("ReplyAction");
            var replyActionValue = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}Response", nameSpace, method.DeclaringType.Name, method.Name);

            var attribuiteBuilder = 
                new CustomAttributeBuilder(
                    operationContractConstructor, 
                    new object[0],
                    new[] { asynchPatternProperty, actionProperty, replyActionProperty },
                    new object[] { true, actionValue, replyActionValue });



            methodBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attribuiteBuilder);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// provides a ModelBuilder with the required assembly name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requiredAssemblyName">the assembly name for where the type will be generated in</param>
        /// <returns>a model builder</returns>
        /// <remarks>in this version the model builder is not cached, it could be interesting to generate all the types in the same assembly by caching the model builder</remarks>
        private ModuleBuilder GetModuleBuilder(string requiredAssemblyName)
        {
            if (moduleBuilderCache.ContainsKey(requiredAssemblyName))
            {
                return moduleBuilderCache[requiredAssemblyName];
            }

            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(requiredAssemblyName);
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                    assemblyName,
                    AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name);

            moduleBuilderCache[requiredAssemblyName] = moduleBuilder;

            return moduleBuilder;
        }
    }
```

and **TypeExtentions** Class

```
public static class TypeExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// extracts all the methods fromthe given interface type and from all the inherited ones too
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">the type fromwhich extracts all the methods</param>
        /// <returns>list of MemberInfo representing the methods</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetAllInterfaceMethods(this Type type)
        {

            IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = type.GetMethods();
            foreach (var subType in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                methods = methods.Union(GetAllInterfaceMethods(subType));
            }
            return methods;
        }
    }
```

I 'm able to convert a Synchronous Interface to Asynchronous one.

**How** to use [DuplexChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576164.aspx) with a pre-defined reflection Asynchronous interface ?

```
var myInterface = new TypeGenerator ( ) . GenerateAsyncInterfaceFor<mySynchronousInterface> ( );

var Client = new DuplexChannelFactory<myInterface> ( new InstanceContext ( new myClass ( ) ) , "myConfiguration" );
```

I'm getting the following issue:

> The type or namespace name 'myInterface' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm trying to code a mid-tier WCF interface.

Comment: Can you post the code which is causing the error please.

Comment: @hugh More details added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using is for compile time typing, of course the types you are making are generated at runtime, so it isn't going to work. It is possible though.
[How to: Examine and Instantiate Generic Types with Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx)

Here's how the code will look (I'm assuming myClass was already defined with source code, if not it would just be another Activator.CreateInstance call)

```
Type t = typeof(DuplexChannelFactory<>);
Type typedDuplexChannelFactory = t.MakeGenericType(new Type[]{myInterface});
var Client = Activator.CreateInstance(typedDuplexChannelFactory, new object[]{new InstanceContext ( new myClass ( ) ) , "myConfiguration"});
```